# rdpsign failing with error 0x80092004

Tags: ssl-certificate, rdp, windows-server-2016

On an RDSH server running Windows Server 2016, the following certificate is installed:

- Issued by: `COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA`
- Issued to: `*.internal.<Internet domain name>`
- Valid from: 2017/07/18
- Valid to: 2018/07/19
- SHA-1 thumbprint: `‎02 e5 52 95 aa 2d 9f a5 fb ad 82 97 0e 66 5d a9 73 db 00 ca`
- Private key: Yes

We need to sign an RDP file using the above certificate and research strongly suggests using rdpsign.

I executed command `rdpsign -?` which ouputted the following:

```
NAME

rdpsign [options] [items to sign]

OPTIONS

  /sha256 HASH
       Specified the SHA256 hash of the signing certificate.
  /q
       Quiet mode:  No output when success, minimal output when failed.
  /v
       Verbose mode:  Display all warnings, messages, and status.
  /l
       Test signing and output results without actually replacing any of the inputs.  Ignores when input files are on stdin.


All rdp file(s) have been succesfully signed.
```

So, contrary to [the official, now-outdated documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753982(v=ws.11).aspx), `rdpsign` requires the certificate's SHA-256 hash.

However, IIS Manager and Certificate Manager only offer certificates' SHA-1 thumbprints.

https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/identity-protection-support/index?page=content&id=SO28771&actp=RSS&viewlocale=en_US advises that OpenSSL can be used to obtain a certificate's various hashes, including SHA-256.

I exported the certificate without its private key to a base-64 encoded X.509 CER file.

I executed command `openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha1 -inform pem -in <file name>.cer` which ouputted the following:

```
SHA1 Fingerprint=02:E5:52:95:AA:2D:9F:A5:FB:AD:82:97:0E:66:5D:A9:73:DB:00:CA
```

So, we can be confident that OpenSSL is outputting accurate information because the SHA-1 thumbprints match.

I executed command `openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha256 -inform pem -in <file name>.cer` which ouputted the following:

```
SHA256 Fingerprint=D7:44:A5:BA:94:56:B0:9F:26:D2:2B:88:92:84:11:74:35:23:71:87:30:FD:CE:D0:B1:35:6B:D8:DA:A6:A1:7B
```

I executed elevated (run as administrator) commands `rdpsign /sha256 D744A5BA9456B09F26D22B88928411743523718730FDCED0B1356BD8DAA6A17B <file name>.rdp /v`, `rdpsign /sha256 "D744A5BA9456B09F26D22B88928411743523718730FDCED0B1356BD8DAA6A17B" <file name>.rdp /v`, and `rdpsign /sha256 d744a5ba9456b09f26d22b88928411743523718730fdced0b1356bd8daa6a17b <file name>.rdp /v` all of which outputted the following:

```
Unable locate the certificate specified.  Error Code: 0x80092004
The rdp file could not be signed.  Error Code: 0x80092004
```

I've found that there's hardly anything relevant online for this problem. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the parameter name is misleading. It seems to assume it will use SHA-256 algorithm to sign the file, but accepts SHA-1 certificate thumbprint as a value.

Tested **rdpsign.exe** on **Windows 10** machine and was able to sign an RDP file using a SHA-1 thumbprint of an installed certificate that has Signature Hash Algorithm SHA-256. If your certificate can sign it, the following command should do it.

`rdpsign.exe /sha256 02e55295aa2d9fa5fbad82970e665da973db00ca <rdp file path>`

When I use an older cert that has SHA-1 signature algorithm, rdpsign.exe generates the error:

> Unable to use the certificate specified for signing.  Error Code:
>   0x8007000d The rdp file could not be signed.  Error Code: 0x8007000d

Comment: Command `rdpsign /sha256 02e55295aa2d9fa5fbad82970e665da973db00ca <file name>.rdp` outputted `All rdp file(s) have been succesfully signed.`. Opening the RDP file shows the correct certificate but says `Do you trust the publisher of this remote connection?` and its properties window doesn't have a `Digital Signatures` tab? Is that normal?

Comment: @mythofechelon I wouldn't go as far as saying that this is normal, but it is one step up from an untrusted cert or unsigned rdp file. We have an RD Gateway that uses a trusted wildcard certificate issued by thawte, but produces the same question upon connection. Note that it is informational and not warning.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. An unsigned RDP file says `The publisher of this remote connection can't be identified. Do you want to connect anyway?` so it's not perfect but it's an improvement. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Regarding the missing `Digital Signatures` tab, signing RDP files seems to work by adding `signscope` and `signature` into the **content** of the file, whereas signing EXE, etc files seems to work by adding the details to the metadata of the file.

Comment: Also, a quick search suggested putting the hash in quotes and using a short filename for the RDP file

Answer (score 0):

**According to Microsoft Article** [Remote Desktop listener certificate configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-listener-certificate-configurations)...

> Before you run the wmic commands, the certificate that you want to use
> must be imported to the Personal certificate store for the computer
> account. If you do not import the certificate, you will receive an
> Invalid Parameter error.

Meaning:

Click **Star Menu**, type `certlm.msc` then hit Enter to open Certificates Local Computer.

Select **Personal store** and Right-Click to **Import** `.pfx` or `.p12` certificate.

Once imported, double-click the Certificate, click Details tab and scroll down to Thumbprint Field.

[image]

[image]